# How can I count number of columns whose name starts with specific words

Tags: python, pandas

In my python dataframe I have around 40 columns. Out of these 40 columns around 20 columns starts with `"Name_"` for example `"Name_History","Name_Language`" and remaining column starts with `"score_"` for example "Score_Math","Scor_Physisc".

I would like to determine dynamically First & last index of columns starting with `"Name_"` .

Comment: At least you could give the input and give the expected output and let others do the rest, you didn't describe the question right

Comment: For each column name; if the name starts with `Name_`; store that column's index in a container.

Comment: Is your question to count the columns or to get the first/last index? (Your title and body don't quite match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to return an array with first and last:

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Name_')][[0,-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To additionally answer the question that is asked in the title:

You can use this, to get the number of columns starting with `'Name_'`:

```
df.columns.str.startswith('Name_').sum()
```